# Two different image onLoad

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently I only have one image onLoad everytime when i run my animation.

```
var imgFish = new Image();
imgFish.onload = init;
imgFish.src = 'Image';
```

I'm  try to make two or more different image to load at the same time.

I have only one orange fish moving on the canvas when i press on the 'Add a fish!' button. I want to make more different fish swimming on the canvas too. I have created another button called 'Add a different color fish!', I want to add a fish but with a different image with the same code to allow the fish to animation on the canvas.

Anyone knows how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/qx3tq5bL/1/

Your code requires a image object to create a new fish in the constructor of Fish. Thus you need to do 2 things:

First, Create a new image object pointing to a different image of a fish of different color

```
var imgFish2 = new Image();
imgFish2.onload = init;
imgFish2.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0q7o0i23xmz719m/FishStrip.png';
```

Second, Bind function to your new button in function init:

```
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
  // create another fish using the Fish class
  var anotherFish = new Fish(xPos, yPos, speedX, speedY, imgFish2, frameWidth, frameHeight);
  // put this new fish into the fishes[] array
  fishes.push(anotherFish) ;
  // make it start changing directions
  anotherFish.changeDirection();
  // draw this new fish
  anotherFish.drawFish();
}
```

Comment: The problem is with line 83, the Fish class is now showing image using this.image, instead, it used global imgFish. see http://jsfiddle.net/8gTNk/20/

Comment: Your code does not have any frame rate control, it request for next frame as soon as it start painting(line 90).Thus it is up to the browser to decide how fast the next paint event is called. Adding a setTimeout for requesting next frame time. See http://jsfiddle.net/8gTNk/22/ for an example. However, as the code move the fish every time the paint is called, thus if the browser decide not to repaint, the fish would be moving very slow. To properly implement a fresh rate independent animation, you need to make use the timestamp variable passed in from the callback to calculate how much to move.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic image loader that preloads all your images and then calls start()

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push all your image urls!
imageURLs.push("");

// the loaded images will be placed in images[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```